# Should I use stack or heap memory for classes in a game? C++

Tags: c++, game-development

So I’m writing a console game in c++. I have enemy classes, will have a player class soon, im gonna have projectile classes (hopefully I can figure out some way to help performance all of these objects) and I was wondering whether the heap or the stack would be better to allocate memory to. I know the stack is faster, but if I initialize a class in main() would it ever be destroyed?

Comment: You already know the answer - it's based on object lifetime.  If something needs to live beyond the end of the function that created it, it needs to go on the heap.

Comment: If the number of (some type of) objects is unknown at compile time, or the objects are quite "large" (depends on a lot of things, including the target platform) dynamic allocation is appropriate.  If not, automatically or statically allocated objects are (often) appropriate. Bear in mind, in C++, that automatically allocated objects may manage lifetime of dynamically allocated objects (e.g. standard containers, smart pointers).  Stack and heap aren't actually terms in standard C++ - but implementations often use heap for dynamically allocated objects and stack for automatic and static objects

Comment: @Peter actually static objects usually get their own memory that is neither stack nor heap.